# Multiple columns after WHERE statement that uses LIKE SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

i am tying to do a query like this

```
select * from tablename where column1 or column2 or column3 like '%input%';
```

but it only seems to do the query to the last column.

How can i query so it looks for that input in all three columns and outputs me with whatever matches from any of those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the condition:

```
where column1 like '%input%' or
      column2 like '%input%' or
      column3 like '%input%'
```

`or` connects boolean expressions in SQL.  It does not connect operands, such as the string comparison for `like`.